# Linking Robomongo to an automatic email sending service?

Tags: meteor

I have an application running on meteor.js and mongo.db. I am using robomongo as a tool for mongo.db. Now I'd like to do the following: 
1. Somebody registers with my service (adding email to db)
2. I want to send an automatic welcome email to that person.

Is there any possibility how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need an email server (SMTP), and then use  [the meteor email library](http://docs.meteor.com/#email). If you don't have an email server and don't want to create one, use a commercial solution. ([Example](http://sendgrid.com/blog/send-email-meteor-sendgrid/))

Answer (score 0):

**Full working example you can find here**: http://meteorpad.com/pad/iNMBHtNsv7XKHeq44

Notice it creates new users from within Meteor app, but the same effect will be when you use Robomongo or any other way of updating MongoDB.

First install package `Email` to be able to use `Email.send`. 
In below example I assume that adding new user to collection Meteor.users should fire sending "invitation" email.
In very similar way you can detect if email was added to user object 
(`user.emails.length` was changed) and then send email.

Then take a look at code:

```
// SERVER SIDE CODE:
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // clean users on app resetart
  // Meteor.users.remove({});

  if(Meteor.users.find().count() === 0){
     console.log("Create users");
     Accounts.createUser({
       username:"userA",
       email:"userA@example.com",
       profile:{
         invitationEmailSend:false
       }
     })  ;
     Accounts.createUser({
       username:"userB",
       email:"userB@example.com",
       profile:{
         invitationEmailSend:false
       }
     })  
  }
  Meteor.users.find().observe({
    added:function(user){
        console.log(user.username, user.profile.invitationEmailSend)
        if(!user.profile.invitationEmailSend){
            Email.send({
              from: "from@mailinator.com",
              to: user.emails[0].address,
              subject: "Welcome",
              text: "Welcome !"
            });
            // set flag 'invitationEmailSend' to true, so email won't be send twice in the future ( ex. during restart of app)
            Meteor.users.update({_id:user._id},{$set:{"profile.invitationEmailSend":true}});
        }
    }
  })
});
```

Above code will send email to users who don't have flag equal to true in `profile.invitationEmailSend`. After e-mail is sent server updates user document in db and set `user.profile.invitationEmailSend` to true.

Whenever you add users to mongoDB (using Robomongo or any other way), then `added` function is executed and e-mail is send only to new users.